# "Repeatable read" vs Optimistic

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql, transactions

What is the difference between concurrency control and transaction isolation levels?

I understand each of them clearly, however, I am having some problems relating them to each other. Specifically, I see some overlap in their functions and I'm not sure when one should use one over the other. Or should both be used together?

Also what does it mean to say pessimistic locking with repeatable read? Doesn't repeatable read already imply that all values to be edited will be locked? So why is there still a need for pessimistic locking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue arises because there are two models for concurrency control, which are sometimes mixed by SQL implementations.

1. locks, as in 2PL (Two Phase Locking)
2. versions, as in MVCC (Multiversion Concurrency Control)

Pessimistic means rows that are read are locked. Optimistic means rows that are read are not locked.

The classic 2PL implementation of Repeatable Read is always pessimistic. The multiversion implementation of Repeatable Read is optimistic. It does not lock the rows that are read for a SELECT statement and allows other transactions to modify the rows that have been read in a SELECT. Such changes are not visible to the transaction that performed the SELECT, until it is committed.

Comment: When other transactions make changes and commit, the changes will be visible to the transaction that performed the SELECT immediately, right? How repeatable-read is achieved?

Comment: When the session is `READ COMMITTED` by default but usually you can set it to REPEATABLE READ. For example with `SET TRANSACTION REPEATABLE READ` in HSQLDB.

Answer (score 5):

*Concurrency control* is a general term for any mechanism that handles issues that arise from concurrent connections.

*Transaction isolation levels* are a mechanism by which MySQL implements concurrency control.

See [Consistent Nonlocking Reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-consistent-read.html) for documentation on how MySQL implements `REPEATABLE READ` without pessimistic locking:

> A consistent read does not set any locks on the tables it accesses, and therefore other sessions are free to modify those tables at the same time a consistent read is being performed on the table.
>
> Suppose that you are running in the default `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level. When you issue a consistent read (that is, an ordinary `SELECT` statement), InnoDB gives your transaction a timepoint according to which your query sees the database. If another transaction deletes a row and commits after your timepoint was assigned, you do not see the row as having been deleted. Inserts and updates are treated similarly.